# Setting opacity by javascript when freeze is used

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an animation on an image that fades the image in after 2 seconds and keeps the image visible after the animation completed by using fill="freeze".

The animation is working as expected.

How can I change the opacity by javascript when freeze is set? Right now I can not change opacity in the script. If I remove freeze my script works, but the animation is not working anymore as expected (Then the image gets invisible after the completion finished )

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
window.onload = function() {
img1.addEventListener("click", clickImg);
};

function clickImg(event)
{
        event.target.setAttribute("opacity",'0');
}
</script>
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" >


   <image x="25%" y="25%" width="30%" height="30%" id="img1" 
   opacity="0"

   preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
     xlink:href="img/3dugs.jpg" >

      <animate attributeName="opacity" 
       fill="freeze"
   attributeType="CSS" 
   begin="2s" dur="2s" from="0" to="1" 
   repeatCount="1" />

     </image>
  </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you hoping should happen when the image is clicked on?

Comment: It should get invisible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the animationEnd event to know when the animation has finished. In the handler, remove the animation and set opacity = 1:

Here is a cross-browser code that does that:

```
$('#img1').bind('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(){
    //remove the animation here.
    $(this).css('opacity', 1);
});
```

I suppose you make the animation start by setting a CSS class to the image that includes the animation. In the handler I gave you, remove said class and set opacity to 1.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The animation is not startet by a scipt. It just runs because it is a child elment of the image. But I will still try to remove it by a script.

Comment: I see. Well, in the comment part of my code, just remove the animation using the DOM (I think it's done that way, I've never used SVG)

Comment: Removing the animation by calling img1.removeChild(img1.firstChild) and setting the the opacity after that to 1 worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to make the image invisible, you can remove it from the DOM tree:

```
var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
window.onload = function() {
    img1.addEventListener("click", clickImg);
};

function clickImg(event) {
    img1.style.display = "none";
}
```

You can test it here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/8pvQ6/)